# Mail sent to root never arrives

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail

If I send emails with

```
echo "test" | mail -s "Test" myuser
echo "test" | mail -s "Test" root
```

/var/log/mail.log contains

```
Apr  7 16:30:30 ScotLX postfix/pickup[247827]: 46871740CE7: uid=1000 from=<myuser@ScotLX>
Apr  7 16:30:30 ScotLX postfix/cleanup[249740]: 46871740CE7: message-id=<20220407143030.46871740CE7@ScotLX.fritz.box>
Apr  7 16:30:30 ScotLX postfix/qmgr[247828]: 46871740CE7: from=<myuser@ScotLX>, size=325, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  7 16:30:30 ScotLX postfix/local[249742]: 46871740CE7: to=<myuser@ScotLX>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Apr  7 16:30:30 ScotLX postfix/qmgr[247828]: 46871740CE7: removed
Apr  7 16:30:40 ScotLX postfix/pickup[247827]: 801EE740CE7: uid=1000 from=<myuser@ScotLX>
Apr  7 16:30:40 ScotLX postfix/cleanup[249740]: 801EE740CE7: message-id=<20220407143040.801EE740CE7@ScotLX.fritz.box>
Apr  7 16:30:40 ScotLX postfix/qmgr[247828]: 801EE740CE7: from=<myuser@ScotLX>, size=325, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  7 16:30:40 ScotLX postfix/local[249742]: 801EE740CE7: to=<root@ScotLX>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Apr  7 16:30:40 ScotLX postfix/qmgr[247828]: 801EE740CE7: removed
```

That looks to me to be OK, but ls -la /var/mail/ returns

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 root   mail   4096 Apr  7 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root   root   4096 Jun 24  2020 ..
-rw-r-----  1 myuser mail 169303 Apr  7 16:35 myuser
-rw-r-----  1 root   mail      0 Apr  5 19:17 root
```

and 'sudo mail' returns

```
No mail for root
```

/etc/hosts contains

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ScotLX ScotLX.fritz.box
```

and /etc/mailname contains

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ScotLX ScotLX.fritz.box
```

/etc/aliases contains

```
postmaster:    root
```

Where have root's emails gone? Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution?

Comment: `grep -w root: /etc/aliases` please (just add the entry/entries - if any - to your existing block for `/etc/aliases`. No need for "edit" - we can all see the changes  anyway)

Comment: Email is being delivered via `procmail -a "$EXTENSION"`. You need to find out what delivery recipe your `procmail` is actioning. Look at `/etc/procmailrc` and `~root/.procmailrc`, as well as the contents of the directory `/etc/procmailrcs`

Comment: @roaima neither the files not the directory exist by me.